# Magento 2 : How to create shipment label programmatically

Tags: shipping, magento2.2.3, fedex

I am currently building a functionality to **create order,invoice and shipment** via script.

I can create **shipment with tracking ID** programmatically but could not create **shipment label** via script.

I am using **FedEx shipping method**. please help how to create *shipment label* for **FedEx** programmatically.

Comment: Were you able to get a response?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/157599)